# How to setup Nuxt for an isomorphic universal app?

Tags: nuxt.js

I was wondering how to use my Nuxt app into an isomorphic universal mode.
What I mean, is that I do want to use it with SSR and SPA at the same time.
I know that it can support both but I cannot see where to setup it properly.

I saw the [`mode` property](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-mode) but I'm not sure to understand where to write it (in the `nuxt.config.js` file?).
Nor where to put the `mode` key.

Are `mode: universal` or `mode: spa` outdated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An image summing up all the different approaches can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63638062/8816585

`mode` is **now deprecated** as shown in [the documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-mode)

If you want to use your Nuxt app in an isomorphic (aka *Universal*) way, you need to have:

- `ssr: true`
- either `target: server` (default) or `target: static`