# 'NUXT_ENV_STAGE' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm trying to set up an environment for a nuxt.js app. but I'm getting this error every time.

> 'NUXT_ENV_STAGE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

What does this mean and how can I solve this problem?

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "4u2-frontend-business",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "4u2 for business",
  "author": "fjzy-web",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "4u2-common"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NUXT_ENV_STAGE=dev PORT=3100 NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server",
    "build": "NUXT_ENV_STAGE=production NODE_ENV=production nuxt build",
    "start": "NUXT_ENV_STAGE=production NODE_ENV=production node server/index.js",
    "prettier": "prettier  --write \"**/*.{vue,js,jsx,json,css}\" --ignore-path .prettierignore && npm run lint",
    "generate": "NUXT_ENV_STAGE=production NODE_ENV=production nuxt generate",
    "lint": "eslint --fix --ignore-path .gitignore ./src/**/*.{vue,js}",
    "et": "node_modules/.bin/et -w -c src/assets/element-variables.scss -o ./assets/theme",
    "styleguide": "vue-styleguidist server --config styleguide.config.js",
    "styleguide:build": "vue-styleguidist build --config styleguide.config.js",
    "test:unit": "jest -c ./jest/jest.config.unit.js --watch",
    "test:e2e": "JEST_PUPPETEER_CONFIG=./jest/jest-puppeteer.config.js jest -c ./jest/jest.config.e2e.js --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sentry/integrations": "5.10.2",
    "@shopify/app-bridge": "^1.28.0",
    "core-js": "3",
    "vue-codemirror-lite": "1.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.31",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "25.1.0",
    "jest": "25.1.0",
    "jest-puppeteer": "4.4.0",
    "puppeteer": "2.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "7.3.1",
    "vue-jest": "3.0.5",
    "vue-styleguidist": "3.22.3"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.js": [
      "eslint --fix --cache --ignore-path .gitignore --ext .js",
      "git add"
    ],
    "src/**/*.vue": [
      "eslint --fix --cache --ignore-path .gitignore --ext .vue",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
}
```

And my `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
//  my nuxt.config.js file
/* eslint-disable global-require */
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const FilterWarningsPlugin = require('webpack-filter-warnings-plugin')
const i18n = require('./4u2-common/config/i18n')
require('dotenv').config({ path: `.env.${process.env.NUXT_ENV_STAGE}` })
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
const resolve = (dir) => path.join(__dirname, dir)

module.exports = {
  telemetry: false,
  srcDir: 'src/',
  styleResources: {
    scss: '~/assets/css/variables.scss',
  },
  mode: 'spa',
  dir: {
    middleware: 'middleware',
  },
  head: {
    title: 'Distribute & Dropshipping Online Customization Products',
    meta: [{ charset: 'utf-8' }, { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' }],
  },
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/style-resources',
    ['nuxt-i18n', i18n],
    ['@nuxtjs/dotenv', { filename: `../.env.${process.env.NUXT_ENV_STAGE}` }],
    '@nuxtjs/gtm',
  ],
  gtm: {
    id: process.env.GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID ? process.env.GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID : '',
    enabled: !!process.env.GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID,
  },
  env: {
    stage: 'dev',
  },
  plugins: [
    '~~/4u2-common/plugins/consoledev.js',
    '~~/4u2-common/plugins/lodash.js',
    '~/plugins/sentry.js',
    '~~/4u2-common/plugins/array-extends.js',
    '~~/4u2-common/plugins/i18n-patch.js',
    '~~/4u2-common/plugins/price-converter.js',
    '~~/4u2-common/plugins/axios/index.js',
    '~~/4u2-common/plugins/error-handler.js',
    '~~/4u2-common/plugins/dispatch.js',
    '~/plugins/init.js',
    '~~/4u2-common/plugins/route.js',
    '~~/4u2-common/plugins/foru-components.js',
    '~~/4u2-common/plugins/swiper.js',
    '~~/4u2-common/plugins/vee-validate.js',
    '~~/4u2-common/plugins/mixin-methods.js',
    '~~/4u2-common/plugins/mixin-filters.js',
    '~/plugins/auth',
    '~~/4u2-common/plugins/element-ui',
    '~/plugins/init-echarts',
    '~~/4u2-common/plugins/process',
    '~~/4u2-common/plugins/vue-waterfall',
    '~~/4u2-common/plugins/directives/directives',
    '~~/4u2-common/plugins/forudesigner.js',
  ],
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.API_BASE_URL + process.env.API_VERSION,
  },
  render: {
    resourceHints: false,
  },
  // 使vue-router query支持对象
  router: {
    // https://zh.nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components/#disable-prefetching-globally
    prefetchLinks: false,
    parseQuery(q) {
      return qs.parse(q)
    },
    stringifyQuery(q) {
      q = require('~~/4u2-common/utils/helpers').clearEmpties(q)
      const r = qs.stringify(q, { arrayFormat: 'brackets' })
      return r ? '?' + r : ''
    },
  },
  /**
   * global css
   */
  css: [
    '~~/4u2-common/assets/css/foru-icon.css',
    '~~/4u2-common/assets/css/base.scss',
    '~/assets/css/foru-btn.scss',
    '~/assets/css/common.scss',
    'swiper/dist/css/swiper.css',
  ],
  /*
   ** Customize the progress bar color
   */
  loading: { color: '#3B8070' },
  /*
   ** Build configuration
   */
  build: {
    cache: true,
    parallel: true,
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        automaticNameDelimiter: '.',
        maxAsyncRequests: 7,
        cacheGroups: {
          libs: {
            name: 'chunk-libs',
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            priority: 10,
            chunks: 'initial',
          },
          elementUI: {
            name: 'chunk-elementUI',
            priority: 20,
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]_?element-ui(.*)/,
          },
          standardDesigner: {
            name: 'standard-designer',
            priority: 20,
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]_?standard-designer(.*)/,
          },
          commons: {
            name: 'chunk-commons',
            test: resolve('src/components'),
            minChunks: 3,
            priority: 5,
            reuseExistingChunk: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    friendlyErrors: true,
    extractCSS: isProduction,
    filenames: {
      app: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? '[name].js' : `${process.env.MARKETPLACE}.[name].[chunkhash].js`),
      chunk: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? '[name].js' : `${process.env.MARKETPLACE}.[id].[chunkhash].js`),
      css: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? '[name].css' : `${process.env.MARKETPLACE}.[name].[contenthash].css`),
      img: ({ isDev }) =>
        isDev ? '[path][name].[ext]' : `${process.env.MARKETPLACE}.img/[name].[contenthash].[ext]`,
      font: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? '[path][name].[ext]' : `${process.env.MARKETPLACE}.fonts/[name].[ext]`),
      video: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? '[path][name].[ext]' : `${process.env.MARKETPLACE}.videos/[name].[ext]`),
    },
    loaders: {
      imgUrl: {
        limit: isProduction ? 0.1 : 1000,
      },
      vue: {
        productionMode: isProduction,
        transformAssetUrls: {
          video: 'src',
          source: 'src',
          object: 'src',
          embed: 'src',
        },
      },
    },
    publicPath: '/assets/',
    babel: {
      presets: [
        [
          '@babel/preset-env',
          {
            modules: false,
            targets: {
              browsers: ['> 0.1%, edge >= 14, opera >= 60, safari > 11, chrome >= 74, firefox >= 66'],
            },
            useBuiltIns: 'usage',
            corejs: 3,
          },
        ],
      ],
      plugins: [
        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
        [
          '@babel/transform-modules-commonjs',
          {
            allowTopLevelThis: true,
          },
        ],
        [
          'component',
          {
            libraryName: 'element-ui',
            styleLibraryName: 'theme-chalk',
          },
          'element-ui',
        ],
        '@babel/transform-async-to-generator',
        '@babel/transform-runtime',
        '@babel/syntax-dynamic-import',
      ],
      comments: true,
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        qs: 'qs',
      }),
      new FilterWarningsPlugin({
        exclude: /extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin[^]*Conflicting order/,
      }),
    ],
    /**
     * Run ESLint on save
     * @param {object} config config
     */
    extend(config) {
      if (isProduction) {
        config.devtool = 'source-map'
      }
      // use fast-sass-loader instead of sass-loader for now
      config.module.rules = config.module.rules.map((rule) => {
        // sass-loader is only inside "oneOf" attribute
        if (!rule.oneOf) {
          return rule
        }
        const new_rule = rule
        new_rule.oneOf.map((r) => {
          if (!r.use.some((l) => l.loader === 'sass-loader')) {
            return r
          }
          const new_loaders = r
          new_loaders.use = new_loaders.use.reduce((loaderAcc, loader) => {
            if (loader.loader !== 'sass-loader') {
              return [...loaderAcc, ...[loader]]
            }

            return [
              ...loaderAcc,
              ...[
                {
                  loader: 'fast-sass-loader',
                  options: {
                    ...loader.options,
                    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, '/')],
                  },
                },
              ],
            ]
          }, [])
          return new_loaders
        })
        return new_rule
      })
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `NUXT_ENV_STAGE`? Please give us more context.

Comment: I am calling it on my nuxt.config.js  file and try to get from the package.json file for a running developments  server

Comment: here is my package.json script
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "NUXT_ENV_STAGE=dev PORT=3100 NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server",
    "build": "NUXT_ENV_STAGE=production NODE_ENV=production nuxt build",
    "start": "NUXT_ENV_STAGE=production NODE_ENV=production node server/index.js",
  },

Comment: You're not supposed to dump the content of your `package.json` into comments. Nobody will read it. Also, if you're talking about some files, just edit your question with those files.

Comment: Context is important. And the amount of effort put into the question will be more decisive than anything else to succeed into a solution here.

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I share my env and config with you? @kissu

Comment: I am trying to set up env module by package,json script

Comment: Take your files, copy each of them and paste them in your question. Hide the sensitive info, like tokens and passwords if any. Even if you should not have any in those 2 files tbh.

Comment: Please share the whole properly indented files. Not parts of them.

Comment: Alright, I've edited your question. Now we can see what is the matter with all of this.

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow?

Comment: yes, I got a reference from it but still, I am stuck with some issues. it will be fine, thanks, buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Some quick notes of things to fix in your `nuxt.config.js` before proceeding:

- You have some ESlint errors, fix those at some point to prevent further issues.
- You have an old way of importing and using packages in your `nuxt.config.js` file. Since Node v14, and since a lot time on the frontend now, you should rather use `import`.
- As stated on the [official page](https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module) of `nuxt/dotenv`

> With Nuxt v2.13 you might want to migrate from @nuxtjs/dotenv module to use the new runtime config.

So yeah, assuming that you have some kinda latest Nuxt version (and you should), you could ditch `dotenv` since it's already baked in.

- You don't have any `nuxt` package in your `package.json` btw. Not sure why nor how you expect your Nuxt app to work.
- `mode: 'spa'` is obsolete. As pointed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68272664/8816585), only `target` and `ssr` are valid keys as of right now. So the equivalent to `mode: spa` would be `ssr: false`.
- Not sure what you're renaming in `dir`. `middleware` to `middleware`?
- It looks like you're having some dropshipping service here looking at `title: 'Distribute & Dropshipping Online Customization Products'`.
  I should probably stop my answer here, but I'll continue because I'm trying to be professional here.
- The condition here: `id: process.env.GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID ? process.env.GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID : '',` is pretty useless because it's already the behavior of not having a variable set.
- `enabled: !!process.env.GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID` will always be true, no matter what is inside of `GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID`. And btw, you can only have string here, so even if you pass to it `false`, it will be `'false'` at the end, and the result will be `!!'false'` >> `true`.
- code like this: `stage: 'dev',` shows that there is some lack of understanding how to properly handle the various environments. You should not rely on hardcoded variables to set this up. But on a single `.env` with variables inside of it.
  `NODE_ENV` is usually already set for you and you can just rely on this for your env booleans (even if this should be again, **rarely needed**)
- the rest of the configuration would also probably need some love (won't dive deep in the logical parts of it for obvious time reasons).

---

Still, to answer your initial question, you can follow the link below. Having `NUXT_ENV_STAGE=dev` or setting it into a `.env` will lead to the same results and is used the same way (aka `process.env.NUXT_ENV_STAGE`).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585